# How does coding the pause and resume commands work when coding a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I have tried to code a music bot of sorts, and it the code I put for the pause command doesn't work. I don't know about the resume command, since I'd have to first get the pause command working.

Here is the code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
  if (ctx.author.voice):
    vc = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await vc.connect()
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('Forest Battle - Battle music.mp3')
    player = voice.play(source)
  else: 
    await ctx.send("You need to be in a voice channel before using this command!")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
  if (ctx.voice_client):
    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("`RSS Dnd Bot has left the voice channel!`")
  else:
    await ctx.send("`RSS Dnd Bot isn't currently in any voice channel!`")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def pause(ctx):
  voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  if voice.is_playing():
    voice.pause
  else: 
    await ctx.send("`Nothing is currently playing right now!`")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def resume(ctx):
  voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  if voice.is_paused():
    voice.resume()
  else:
    await ctx.send("`Nothing is currently paused right now!`")
```

Comment: Can you specify how does the code not behave as intended? It will help provide context for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This is my pause command:

```py
@client.command(name='pause', description="pauses music")
    async def pause_(ctx):
        """Pause the currently playing song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_playing():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I am currently not playing anything", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        elif vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused ⏸️")
```

This is my resume command:

```py
@client.command(name='resume', description="resumes music")
    async def resume_(ctx):
        """Resume the currently paused song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        elif not vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resuming ⏯️")
```